# Getting if image on canvas was clicked Javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I have currently got a canvas which contains many picture. I need to know if a image is clicked and what image it was. I can get the mouse position like below

```
function getPosition(event)
{
  var mousex = event.x;
  var mousey = event.y;



  mousex -= canvas.offsetLeft;
  mousey -= canvas.offsetTop;

  //alert("x:" + mousex + " y:" + mousey);

}
```

And my images are like shown below

```
g.drawImage(img1, 100, 50, 300,300);
   g.drawImage(img2, 300, 50, 300,300); 
   g.drawImage(img3, 10, 20, 300,300);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already have the local position of the mouse in the canvas, it suffices that you store the image positions and size in an array, ordered by appearance. According to your case you will end up with an array:

```
[[img3, 10, 20, 300, 300], [img2, 300, 50, 300, 300], [img1, 100, 50, 300, 300]]
```

Then every time you handle a mouse click, iterate the above array and check whether or not the mouse position is contained in the image by the following code:

```
(mousex >= img.x) && (mousex < img.x + img.width) && (mousey >= img.y) && (mousey < img.y + img.height)
```

As soon as you find that the mouse is contained in an image, return that image and stop the iteration.
If the iteration ends without image hit, you might return `null` or `false`